# ¿Qué hacer en CSS3 para que no se desborde todo el contenido del ancho y aparezca scroll?

Tags: html, css, css3

Estoy tratando de acomodar todo mi contenido en lo ancho de la página con CSS, pero resulta que desde el body se desborda y aparese un scroll horizontal.

Lo pongo como `width: 0 auto`, pero sigue igual.

Tengo entendido que una buena página no debe tener scroll horizontal, ¿cómo corrijo eso?

Comment: Hola @GDeGilberto. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! ¿Podrías incluir el html y el css de tu página? Realmente ayudaría a que alguien que quiera ayudarte pueda contextualizar cuál es tu problema puntual. Encontrarás el enlace para [edit] debajo de tu pregunta y, en el editor, un botón para agregar código HTML/CSS/JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la forma más sencilla sería así , asignando la propiedad   [overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)-x `:` `hidden`(*Horizontal*)   Para  que **El contenido sea recortado y no se muestren barras de posición (`scroll`).** y adicionalmente `overflow-y: scroll;` para que si se muestre el scroll en `Y` - *(vertical)*

```
html, body {
   max-width: 100%;
   overflow-x: hidden;
   overflow-y: scroll;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Intenta utilizando una de estas 3 propiedades CSS :

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
// Crea saltos de linea

word-break: break-all;
// Acomoda el texto dentro del contenedor.

word-wrap: break-word;
// Lo mismo que word-break solo que crea saltos de linea.
```

Por mi parte te recomiendo que uses las 3 al mismo tiempo. :)